# Should I use std::list or is there a better method?

Tags: c++, list, geometry, deque

I am currently coding in a 2D geometry editor in c++. I am having the user place nodes. Lines and arcs can be drawn by selecting 2 nodes.

Right now, I am storing the nodes in a std::deque container (same thing for the lines and arcs) because I would like to store the address of the node into each line/arc. This makes things very convenient coding wise when I implement a feature to move the node. If I were to store the actual node inside of each line/arc, then when I want to move a node, then I would have to iterate through the entire line and arc stucture to find the node that I just moved and update the parameters. This option isn't an option on the table. Hence, the need to be able to store the address of the node inside each line/arc.

However, I am running into some issue where I need to delete the node. Looking on the reference manual, it seems that for all pointer, these are invalidated when you erase an element from the deque (unless that element is at the beginning or the end. For the sake of discussion, I will not be considering this case). This causes issue with the erasing because now, all of my lines/arc reconnect themselves to different nodes or are not drawn at all when a node is erased and the program eventually crashes.

Continuing to look online, I come across std::list which (from my understanding of reading the documentation) does not invalidate any pointers or references when one of the elements is erased. This seems to be a very nice solution to my problem.

However, I have been looking a little bit on stack overflow to see what are the benefits/disadvantages of using a list vs a deque. And it seems like there is more of a preference to use a deque then a list. It seems as though the list is slower to access then the deque. This is not good because I am not sure how many nodes a user would like to draw. For all I know, there could be 10,000+ nodes in the geometry and if the user wants to move a node, I don't want the user have to wait 30 sec for the program to iterate through all of the elements to find the node(s) to erase.

So on one hand, deque are alot faster but as soon as an element is removed, all of the pointers and references are invalidated. On the other hand, std::list allows me to erase whatever element I want without invalidating any of the pointers and references but is slower compared to a deque.

I am considering to switch to a list because even if the list is slower, if I can't erase an element without invalidating the pointers and references, then there isn't much of a benefit speed wise if the program doesn't work.

However, is using a list the best choice in my situation? Is there any way to use a deque? Or is there a third option that I haven't considered?

Edit:

I forgot to mention. One thing that I am not to fond of with lists is the inability to get an element's data directly (in std::deque and vector, I can use the at function to access elements). This isn't a huge deal breaker with my code. But it does makes things convenient. For example, when a user selects a node when they want to create a line/arc, the code iterates over the entire node list to find out which one was selected and then, for the first selection, stores the index into a variable (called firstNodeIndex). For the second node, it does the same thing but when both variables (firstNodeIndex and secondNodeIndex) are viable numbers, then the function for creating the line/arc is called and the function uses the two stored indexes to re-access the node list to grab an address to the node. If I were to use the list, I would have to store the address of the two nodes in variables and then create some additional logic to make sure that the two variables containing the addresses to the two nodes are viable options.

Another alternate solution would be to reiterate through the entire node list again to grab the nodes that are selected (I would have a variable inside each node to indicate that it is selected). But I am afraid that this might not be a good idea given std::list limitations.

I am kind of in favor of my first way but I am open to change if need be or if there is a better method

Comment: as per my (downvoted?) answer - use a map. map node id to node. insertions and deletions in a map don't invalidate iterators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that you don't want your iterators invalidated when you insert or erase element, but you want your data structure to be fast.

Linked list is only slow when you have to iterate all elements frequently. In does not take advantage of continuous data access like vector or deque. Also linear search in list is slow.

I had similar situations. Here are some options:

1. Use list and try to avoid linear searches. See if memory access speed of linked list affect your performance significantly and if it doesn't - use it.
2. Use map or set. Same cons as list except search, which is O(logn). Or you can use unordered versions if you don't care about sorting elements.
3. Use non-standard data structure like [`plf::colony`](http://plflib.org/colony.htm). If you don't care about order of insertion, this is probably your best option.
4. Create your own deque-like data structure that does not invalidate iterators (using skipfields or storing free elements somewhere). I wouldn't recommend it since you will probably end up writing something like `plf::colony` anyway.

Comment: Skimming through plf::colony, this seems like a viable option. I just need to make sure that there isn't a case where the order of insertion is important (which, I don't think so). Another downside to the list is that I am not able to access an element directly. (Please see my edit for further information)

Comment: I didn't fully understand your edit. What is the difference between storing indexes and storing iterators? Also note that colony also does not allow random access.

Comment: Storing iterators? I haven't considered that. Still learning how to use iterators and what not. At first I was using the index to quickly reaccess the vector/deque to grab the node. But I guess the iterator can do the same thing but with less steps involved. Although, how would I make sure that the iterator is valid and how can I reset the iterator to a default value for the next combination of selection?

Comment: Iterators don't have to be specifically `std::list::iterator`. Pointers can be called iterators too. If you are using `list::iterator`, then you can't check its validity. If it is invalidated, you can't access it (not only you can't dereference it, but any access at all). This goes for pointers as well: once you free memory, you can't access it. As for resetting: you can assign nullptr to pointer or default-construct an iterator (`it = std::list<mytype>::iterator()`).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, let me try a few things from your options to determine which method I should take. I should be updating the acceptance of the question hopefully soon

Answer (score -2):

A rule of thumb:

will I want to add and delete items at random?

```
set, list, map, multimap and unordered versions of same
```

will I want to be able to name individual items and find them quickly?

```
map, set, multimap and unordered versions of same
```

does the thing I am storing have mutable data, or is it more detailed than just its name (key)?

```
map, multimap, unordered versions thereof
```

do I need the items to say in order?

```
yes: map, no: unordered_map
```